# Basic array doubts

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Quicks
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {   int temp;
        int[] list={5,1,7,6,4,0,8,9};
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
        {
            if(list[i]>list[i+1]);
            {   
                temp=list[i+1];
                list[i+1]=list[i];
                list[i]=temp;
                
            }
        
        }
        for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
            
        }
    }
```

this is the output i am getting
1
7
6
4
0
8
9

> MY first doubt is where  is 5
>
> why is 7 and 6 not being swapped

Comment: never use numeric literals in loop conditions (except 0, 1 or other invariants), use `i < list.length - 1` and `i < list.length` instead

Comment: Have you tried tracking your first cycle eg with debugger, printing out array after every iteration or basically with pen and paper? It can help you understand what happens in your cycles.

Comment: in future better to use list.length instead of putting number into loop

Comment: first `for(i=0;i<=6;i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++)` and the second `for(i=0;i<=6;i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)`

Comment: Use pencil and paper for the same code you design with the same input. It will help you more in debugging and designing.

Comment: My program was to sort these elements using bubble sort but i was not able to develop proper logic for it.Though i tried for 30mins , i wrote down the logic etc on a paper but still i was not able to get out put for this simple program. what is the best approach for solving these problems?

Answer (score 5):

Your first question.

Your loop:

```
for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
{
     System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```

Would be:

```
for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
{
    System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```

because of the size of your array is 8 and no 7, and 6-0+1 = 7, so you don't print the last element.

And if you analize  your code, you will accounts that the loop move the first element of your array to the last position. If you want to sort your array this is not the code.

Comment: Also, there is a semicolon after if(list[i]>list[i+1]); that shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

If you used IDE, it should show you a warning saying that your if statemenet has an empty body - this is because you have put a semicolon at the end of line which shouldn't be there.

I would recommend to put braces `{` at the end of line, rather than the next line to avoid such mistakes.

As for why 5 is not printed - as others mentioned you do not iterate over the entire array.